# How disable same origin policy of iframe inside android webview?

Tags: android, webview, same-origin-policy

We have html page which contains iframe, and there is presented 'X-Frame-Options' header, which is equal to 'sameorigin'.
Is there an option in Android API, for WebView, to disable security policy?